# Sine wave with increasing frequencies in Matlab

Tags: trigonometry, matlab

In my opinion, the following code should produce a sine wave that has a frequency of $2\text{Hz}$ at $t=20$, but when I count the periods between $t=19$ and $t=20$, I count more than 3 periods. What am I doing wrong?

```
clear all, close all, clc;
t=linspace(0,20,10000);
y=sin(2*pi*(1+(5/100)*t).*t);
plot(t,y);
hold on;
```

My plot:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the graph?

Comment: oh my god, sometimes i really gotta hate this website! i was about to post the plot, but stackexchange doesn't alow me to post, because i need at least "10 reputation to post images". wait, i'm gonna figure out another way to share the plot with you

Comment: there you go :)

Comment: The argument of sine function represents the phase function. To find the frequency you have to differentiate it wrt time 't'. In your case you can see why there's an extra factor of 2.

Comment: but if you look at AC-Voltage as an example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current#Mathematics_of_AC_voltages
wikipedia says the voltage is calculated as v(t)=V_peak*sin(omega*t) with omega=2*pi*f. if i replace f in these equations with my varying frequency, i get the function i posted. what is wrong here?

Comment: That wiki formula works for constant frequency only. Frequency w = d/dt (2*pi*f*t) = 2*pi*f. And, w = d/dt (2*pi*k*t*t) = 4*pi*k*t.

Comment: allright, i see. Thank you very much, this solved my problem. you can add this as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of sine function represents the phase of the wave. In general, to find the frequency of the wave at time 't', you have to differentiate it wrt 't'.

f = (1/2*pi) * d/dt (phase).

However for the phase that **linearly varies with time**, i.e., frequency being **independent of time**, you can just divide it by 't'.

f = (1/2*pi) * (1/t) * (phase).

Comment: Btw this is more like physics question. There's stackexchange for physics and other topics also.

Comment: yes, you are right. but when i posted the question i was pretty sure, the function was right and the problem was with matlab. didn't expect, that i was using the wrong correlation between argument of sinus and it's frequency

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at

```
y=sin(2*pi*(1+(5/100)*t).*t);
```

you'll see that the variable $t$ appears to the second power. You've graphed a section of 
$$
y = \sin(C t^2)
$$
rather than 
$$
y = \sin(C t).
$$

Looking closely at your picture, you can see that the spacing of the "humps" changes from left to right, so what you've shown can't possibly be a true sinusoid.

General matlab debugging hint: it's so easy to do stuff -- especially *big* stuff, like building large matrices, or functions represented by 100,000 samples ---  that it's easy to delude yourself into thinking you must have done it right. Always write your code so that you can look at corresponding *small* cases during debugging -- 20 samples of a function of *low* frequency rather than 20,000 samples of a high-freq function, or the 2 x 2 output matrix from a small example rather than the 200 x 200 output from a large one.

Comment: well, unfortunatly this is not an answer to my question at all. i WANTED the t in second power, because i wanted the frequency to increase linear with the time. so the frequency function is something like freq(t)=1+0.05t for a frequency increasing from 1Hz at t=0 to 2Hz at t=20. since a sinus function with a given frequency looks like f(t)=sin(2*Pi*freq*t) i just combined those two and there we go. the only problem is, that the frequency increases a lot faster, than i wanted it to.

Comment: Your question claimed that the code produced a sine-wave, which is what I thought you *wanted* (and which has constant frequency, or it's not a sine-wave). I apologize for reading what you wrote rather than what you meant. I hope I didn't waste your time.

Comment: so if i take a sine of a non-linear function it's not a sine anymore, or what do you want to say? and the title says and always did say "with increasing frequency". Nevertheless sorry for being a little rude and thanks for your attempt to help.

Comment: To be honest...I thought the "with increasing frequency" was characterizing the *problem* you had: you thought it should be a sine, but the frequency wasn't constant the way you expected. (That's how problems in MSE are often written.) I guess it just shows how hard it is to communicate a shared view of something.